# find length of more than 1 input strings

Tags: c, io

How do I find length of more than 1 input strings, without creating multiple char arrays? Do I need to create multiple arrays?

```
//Find Length of string you entered

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>
int main()
{

   char c[100];
   printf("Please enter 2 or more words: \n ");
   scanf("[%s]",c);
   printf("Length is = %ld\n", strlen(c));
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: use `fgets` to read in a string including white spaces.

Comment: Your prompt "Please enter 2 or more words" is followed by `scanf("[%s]",c);` which only reads one word framed by those `[]` characters. The format specifier looks like a hybrid of `%[]`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `scanf("[%s]",c);` you can use `fgets (c, 100, stdin);` to read string from user input.